# возможно ли создать API на фреймворке Django?

Tags: python, django, api

Есть один вопрос. Загуглил, но не смог найти. Вопрос заключается в том что: можно ли создать Бэкенд сайта, т.е API на на фреймворке Django?

Comment: Django позволяет принимать произвольные HTTP-запросы и отправлять произвольные HTTP-ответы, а это автоматически означает, что вы можете реализовать абсолютно что угодно, это даже гуглить не надо

Answer (score 2):

Ответ будет положительный. Данный фреймворк для этого и предназначен.

Что может понадобиться:

[Django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Это для создания полноценного RESTFul API.

Так же, в зависимости от ваших задач и вам нужен REST API вы можете обратить внимание на прекрасный в своей простоте фреймворк [fast API](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), который подходит для разработки на python, и лего/быстро поднять, и использовать.

Comment: django-ninja еще есть, тот же fastapi только под django

Comment: @paqstd, интересно, надо посмотреть что это